# NPE when trying catch onClickListener in listViewItem

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, onclicklistener, getview

i have listView with items, and each item have some buttons and textView and i want to catch clicks on current textView or buttom on current listItem and make some changes with them.
to do this, I am using getView method inside cursorAdapter:

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        View rootView =  super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        mCounter = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView_counter);


        mCounter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int counter = Integer.getInteger(mCounter.getText().toString());
                mCounter.setText(String.valueOf(counter + 1));
                }
            });
            return rootView;
        }
```

but when i am trying to do `mCounter.getText().toString()` i get NPE...

will be glad any ideas how to fix this :)

Comment: Your `mCounter` get overwritten frequently, you shouldn't refer to it anymore. Use `v` instead.

Comment: @haike00 can you give some exampl, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    TextView tv = (TextView)v;
    int counter = Integer.getInteger(tv.getText().toString());
    tv.setText(String.valueOf(counter + 1));
}
```

Make sure that `v` is always a `TextView` (which in your case is) or prepare to catch it with `ClassCastException`.

**UPDATE**

Alright, change the following line

```
int counter = Integer.getInteger(tv.getText().toString());
```

into

```
int counter = Integer.parseInt(tv.getText().toString());
```

**UPDATE 2**

Make sure the value in `TextView` is **number** only or get ready to catch it with `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: thanks, tv is initiated correctly but, i still get npe when trying getText...\

Comment: Do you have nothing in your TextView?

Comment: there number, for example "10"

Comment: thanks!
now my knowledge in this theme is more powerful :)

Comment: No problem, I made mistake as well for overlooking the `Integer` part. And I also learn from there. =)